# How to get Elements from a custom attribute in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I want to extract the text value with javaScript from this below HTML:

```
<div class="search-box-compact__label text-color-secondary">
   <span data-bind="i18n: 'search.keyword-label'">Find Jobs</span>
</div>
```

I have tried this but its not working. Kindly suggest a solution:

```
  let y = document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind=`i18n: 'search.keyword-label'`]");
```

I am getting the following errors::

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[data-bind=`i18n: 'search.keyword-label'`]' is not a valid selector.
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `'`, i used `"` too

```js
let y = document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind=\"i18n: \'search.keyword-label\'\"]");
console.log(y);
```

```html
<div class="search-box-compact__label text-color-secondary">
   <span data-bind="i18n: 'search.keyword-label'">Find Jobs</span>
</div>
```